# What is this error in React and Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I have one mobile app for clients in React Native with Firebase.

Now I am trying to make new program to export data from Firebase Firestore in React.

However I have below error

```
./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/channel.js
 Module not found: Can't resolve 'http2' in
```

What is this error?
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, please, tell us what have you already tried to do in order to solve this problem?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: use react-native-firebase package. https://rnfirebase.io/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's looking for a module that isn't found like it says.

Try running `npm install` again.

Comment: I did that but I couldn't fix it.

Comment: And when I tried to change some my code in this app, this error was removed but I got other error like this "Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase-functions' in ~"

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem with

```
npm install http2
```